# basic html tags inside code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, dynamic

Is it possible to insert bold tag in a Control.Text? Here's my code:

```
Label lab_Name = new Label();
Label lab_actualName = new Label();
lab_Name.Text = "Name: ";
lab_Name.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
lab_actualName.Text = + allRecords[i].name;
```

because I want it to be something like this:

```
<b>Name: </b> Bosiyan
```

but I don't want to separate them and here's what I've been thinking(if possible):

```
Label lab_Name = new Label();
//lab_Name.Text = "<b>Name: </b>" + allRecords[i].name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ASP.NET Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that purpose

```
Literal lit_Name = new Literal();
lit_Name.Text = "<b>Name: </b> Bosiyan";
```

and the text will be rendered as it is, i.e `Name:` will be bold as below

**Name:**  Bosiyan

You can also define the `Literal` control in aspx like this

```
<asp:Literal ID="lit_Name" runat="server" />
```

and set the `Text` property in code behind without initializing `lit_Name`

```
lit_Name.Text = "<b>Name: </b> Bosiyan";
```

Comment: I didn't know something like this exists until now. Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, if i put runat=server inside the tag will I be able to call it in code behind?

Comment: can i do something like this?    lit_Name.Text = "<b runat=server id="Bold_Lit">Name: </b> Bosiyan";

Comment: If you do that, it will render `<b runat=server id="Bold_Lit">Name: </b> Bosiyan`, but you won't be able to access `Bold_Lit` from code behind since it's a static text. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: Nope!I'm just curious! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two labels. So basically anything you want to mark as bold you can use controlstyle as all controls have that property

```
Label a = new Label() {  Text= "test"};
a.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = true;
```